# how useContext hook is working here with useState hook

Tags: reactjs

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
```

this is the place where the actual useContext data is going to be saved `currentUser` and `setCurrentUser`

```
export const UserContext = createContext({
  currentUser: null,
  seCurrentUser: () => null,
});
```

but here is `userProvider` with `useState` Hook and what is
the function of this `useState` Hook here and how `Value` is adding data in `useState` hook, if it is?

```
export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const value = { currentUser, setCurrentUser };
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}> {children} </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

please tell me how it's going to be used in other web pages to collect data it's really confusing for me i'm trying to understand since last week.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i am new here i don't know how to ask questions here, i just mentioned my problem here. that how the above code is working.

Answer (score 2):

> this is the place where the actual useContext data is going to be saved currentUser and setCurrentUser
>
> ```
> export const UserContext = createContext({
>   currentUser: null,
>   seCurrentUser: () => null,
> });
> ```

Actually, this is just the default value. You will not be storing data here, and if a component ever gets these values it means you have forgotten to render a `<UserContext.Provider>`.

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const value = { currentUser, setCurrentUser };
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}> {children} </UserContext.Provider>
  );
```

This is where the work really happens. Your component has a state, which behaves just like any other state in react. The only thing different is that you are then making the current user and the setCurrentUser function available via context, so components farther down the tree can use and change the state.

Context is just a way to pass a value Component A to Component B. You still need to actually implement state or other code to do what you want.

Here's how it looks to consume the context:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  // currentUser is the state found in UserProvider, and setCurrentUser
  //   is the state setter function, also from UserProvider

}
```

Comment: do you mean useContext is being used here to provide setCurrentUser data down into tree components??

Comment: `<UserContext.Provider value={value}>` is what provides the value. `useContext` is what consumes the value